# Adding watermark image to MediaStream

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add image to [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) object that would be over video stream from camera? But not as another layer but like embebed to stream, so if I pass the stream object to some peer it would also have that embebed image.

```
var constraints = { audio: true, video: true };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(mediaStream) {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.srcObject = mediaStream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      video.play();
    };
}).catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
```

As above I just pass mediaStream directly to video element, but can I manipulate stream to add some text or images?

Answer (score 0):

You must manipulate your video stream using a canvas.

If your browser supports `requestVideoFrameCallback`, it should look like that :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(mediaStream) {
    let hiddenVideo = document.querySelector('video.hidden') // A video that is not displayed to the user 
    hiddenVideo.srcObject = mediaStream // Play the stream on the hidden video
    
    let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); // Get a canvas element, by creating or querying it (it may be hidden using 'display:none')
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let rVFC = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(hiddenVideo, 0, 0, hiddenVideo.videoWidth, hiddenVideo.videoHeight); // Draw the video image on your canvas
        // ... Manipulate your canvas here ...
        hiddenVideo.requestVideoFrameCallback(rVFC)
    }
    hiddenVideo.requestVideoFrameCallback(rVFC)
    
    var video = document.querySelector('video.shown');
    video.srcObject = canvas.captureStream(); // Display the canvas edit on the video
}).catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
```

With an html like

```
<video class="hidden" style="display:none" controls autoplay></video>
<video class="shown" controls autoplay></video>
<canvas style="display:none"></canvas>
```

*Notes*:

- If you do not need the video controls, the `video` element is useless, and you can use only the manipulated `canvas` to display the stream.
- If your browser doesn't support `requestVideoFrameCallback`, use `requestAnimationFrame` instead. See https://web.dev/requestvideoframecallback-rvfc/ for more information about `requestVideoFrameCallback`

To send the edited stream to a peer, just use the `MediaStream` created by `canvas.captureStream()`

```
pc.addTrack(capturedStream.getVideoTracks()[0])
```

Comment: Not sure about the culprit being `requestVideoFrameCallback` or `canvas.captureStream` but the generated stream is **paused** (black) if you minimize the window (doesn't happen using the original `getUserMedia` stream. I think we are forced to wait for the ongoing webcodecs standarization processes